# Question on Position absolute, 100% height and the divs below that element

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

I have code like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="has-100-percent-height">
        This div is positioned absolutely and display is none. 
        Overflow auto, too. There are many of these divs within "container"
    </div>
</div>

<div id="the-div-below">
     stuff
</div>
```

When a user clicks a certain link, the "100 percent height" div is to slide down using. What's been happening is that it does slide down, but it doesn't push the div-below down. You can see the content merely display above "the-div-below" and after it slides down, it quickly disappears.

Anyone know what could be going on? This is in firefox 4. I haven't tested other browsers

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have a pretty good idea of what's going on, and how to fix it. So I (and others) can be sure, can you create a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code?

Comment: @thirtydot: i made one here: http://jsfiddle.net/5CZGm/1/    not sure if it's working correctly.. but that pretty much sums up the situation.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. Why does `#outer` have `height: 100%`? No parent element has a defined `height`, so that just comes out as 0 `height`. If you have JavaScript available, this should be very easy (your talk of "sliding down" makes me think you're using it). Can you clarify?

Comment: @thirtydot: I put 100% height on #outer because i was thinking i needed it in order for #outer to fully wrap the absolutely positioned #inner div when #inner had its display set to block. When i say "slide down"  that's ultimately the js effect I would use. It doesn't matter for the problem though, all that matters is that when #inner has display:block, i need for #outer to fully contain it, thus pushing down the div #below.

Comment: What you're asking for (in relation to a sliding effect) is usually handled by JavaScript. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/5CZGm/5/

Answer (score 1):

Is the CSS for your HTML already set in stone? As others have said an *absolutely* positioned element is outside of normal flow therefore cannot affect the position of any other element. If you can remove the `position:absolute` from the `#inner` then the solution is very simple (and just normal browser re-flowing) - see [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MDwUB/).

However if you need to keep the absolute positioning you will have to push `#below` down manually, i.e. JavaScript - see [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MDwUB/2/).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason "the-div-below" is not pushed down is that things that are absolutely positioned don't affect layout of anything else on the page.  That's the whole point of absolute positioning.

So to make things work as you want you need to position your "100 percent height" div either statically or relatively.

The remaining question is how to achieve the layout you want, since presumably there's a reason that you were using absolute positioning?

Comment: I want the container div, which is not positioned absolutely, to completely surround the inner div as it's being slid down; Thus pushing down the div below. I thought that because i have overflow auto on the outer div, the growth of the contents would cause the outer to expand. I hope i'm making sense!

Comment: OK, but why are you absolutely positioning the inner div?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a padding/margin top to the `#the-div-below` that is equal with the 100% height element.